# Type error implementing a map for objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm trying to implement a helper map for objects that looks like this:

```
import { objectEntries, objectFromEntries } from 'ts-extras';

export const map = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: Record<K, V>,
    fn: (key: K, value: V, index?: number) => [K, V]
) => {
    const entries = objectEntries(obj);
    const mappedEntries = entries.map(([key, value], index) => fn(key, value, index));
    return objectFromEntries(mappedEntries);
};
```

But I'm getting the following error in argument key of fn call inside entries.map callback.

```
Argument of type '`${Exclude<K, symbol>}`' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
  '`${Exclude<K, symbol>}`' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PropertyKey'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K'.
      'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PropertyKey'
```

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try: `fn: (key: \`${Exclude<K, symbol>}\`, value: V, index?: number) => [K, V]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type definition of `objectEntries` from `ts-extras` was written in a way to closely reflect the behavior of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries?retiredLocale=de). It knows that `symbol` properties do not appear in the result set and filters them out with `Exclude<K, symbol>`. It also knows that all keys returned from the functions are strings, so it wraps the type in a *template literal type* which converts `number` to `string` and *number literals* to *string literals*.

This results in the type `` `${Exclude<K, symbol>}` ``. While this type is somewhat related to `K`, the compiler correctly denies the assignment.

Changing the type of `key` to `` `${Exclude<K, symbol>}` `` to reflect the typing of `objectEntries` should solve the issue.

```
export const map = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: Record<K, V>,
    fn: (key: `${Exclude<K, symbol>}`, value: V, index?: number) => [K, V]
) => {
    const entries = objectEntries(obj);
    const mappedEntries = entries.map(
      ([key, value], index) => fn(key, value, index)
    );
    return objectFromEntries(mappedEntries);
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgN4KgIwFYFMDGcCiAdnDCFgM4A0qmucAYjFGESWeQgL4IBmTYCAORxyAWiwAPEgENyggNzBgk6PAQ4ohcojDSICALwIAPAGkEkuFkIATDgAUmELPACeprK+oA1AHwAKYARgmgwALgQAJVxYGzMfX0ogkJ5CCP8Aa08IgAMAEiR8CRwAGwBXGyx4hHJXMDQoEt9OHOoAN2lyrAjvahBbSQB+CMIy+pcASkNfBABtUx8AXWApgxmkZOCNLURrNgpDULpWUgp-dAwJxRD1TW0EXQhnGxP2Q73T8gA6R-9-WayXgQHS6iz6AwkqxmqUynnanTKWHBlUhV02CBgWDgZRghCOeEYzFeZ0ez2J5DRnEUwF+G2C0giACIAIwAJgAzIzgJxqLCgSDEcjJFDkMlMdjcXNGdJGdRGWhGctOBMgA)